# Determine total size in Kb of tree with subtrees using terminal

Tags: ubuntu, recursion, terminal, tree

I'm trying to find out the total size of a tree inside a file-system which also includes any files and sub-directories recursively.
And I found somethings online when I searched for it.

First i found something I think I can use to search through a tree recursively which is:

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

And then I found this:

```
du -hs
```

Which should summarizes disk usage of each FILE, recursively for directories.

and hoped I could use them together like this:

```
find . -type f | wc -l | du -hs
```

And I get a result, but how can I check if it's correct? 
Can you do this? Or is it some other command or combination of commands I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last command is simply equivalent to `du -hs` because `du` does not read from stdin and thus does not care what you feed it.

Furthermore `find . -type f | wc -l` does not give you the total file size, it simply *counts the number of files in the current directory*. That is because `wc -l` looks at what you feed it, and count the number of lines, and `find . -type f` simply writes a line (the name of the file) per file it finds in the directory (and its subdirectories).

But `du -hs` should print a oneliner, something like:

```
$ du -hs
874M    .
```

If you want to get the total size of a directory, you can simply feed it as argument, for instance:

```
$ du -hs /home/someuser/
172K /home/someuser/
```

Comment: Ah then I missunderstood what the first command did. Thanks for the explanation! 
Does it go recursively through any sub-tree also?